# Use a proxy with username and password in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to test my web app with different connections and proxies, but i only have authenticated HTTP proxies.
I cannot figure out how to authenticate my proxy before opening the connection.

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
proxy.setHttpProxy("127.0.0.1:3128");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setCapability("proxy", proxy);   
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get("https://www.myip.com/");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the ones that are searching for an answer, i use multipass, chrome extensions filling via selenium the field necessary